# Endless scrolling background

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to get my background to move endless from right to left.

My let:

```
let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
let background2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
```

my didMoveToView

```
background.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    background.zPosition = 2

    background2.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)+(background.position.x/2),CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    background2.zPosition = 2

    background.setScale(2)
    background2.setScale(2)

    self.addChild(background)
    self.addChild(background2)

    var backgroundMovement = SKAction.moveByX(background.size.width, y: 0, duration: 1)
    background.runAction(backgroundMovement, completion: {() -> Void in
        self.background.position = CGPointZero
    })

    var backgroundMovement2 = SKAction.moveByX(background2.size.width, y: 0, duration: 1)
    background2.runAction(backgroundMovement2, completion: {() -> Void in
        self.background2.position = CGPointZero
    })}
```

My update func is empty.

I have uploaded a picture of how it looks like when running on device: http://s18.postimg.org/kbn83tvmx/i_OS_Simulator_Screen_Shot_09_Aug_2015_23_33_39.png

The image is still on half of the screen, and the image does not move now either.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to copy and paste my code from another game I've made. This code moves a background from right-left forever. I'll do best to explain this code.

```
func createBackground () {
    var backgroundTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bg")
    var moveBackgroundByX = SKAction.moveByX(-backgroundTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: backgroundSpeed)
    var replaceBackground = SKAction.moveByX(backgroundTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: 0)
    var moveBackgroundForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([moveBackgroundByX, replaceBackground]))

    for var i:CGFloat = 0; i < 3; i++ {
        background = SKSpriteNode(texture: backgroundTexture)
        background.position = CGPoint(x: backgroundTexture.size().width/2 + (backgroundTexture.size().width * i), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        background.size.height = self.frame.height
        background.runAction(moveBackgroundForever)
        movingObjects.addChild(background)
    }
}
```

What you need to do is:

1. Move background (moveBackgroundByX). This moves the background in the X direction. You need to set a duration.
2. Replace background1 (replaceBackground).
3. Create an ACTION forever that moves background1, then replaces it automatically with NO delay.
4. Run a LOOP that decides how many backgrounds you will need. Maybe you might need more than 3.
5. Inside that loop, adjust the background.position.
6. Call runAction on your SKSpriteNode instance.
7. Add the new SKSpriteNode into your another SKView.

If you have any questions please let me know.

Comment: That's great :D Best of luck finishing the game!

Answer (score 1):

The reason your background only takes up half of the screen is because you are using the regular size of the image in pixels. You need to edit the `xScale` and `yScale` properties in order to make it make it bigger. What you need is:

```
background.setScale(2)
```

Next, to move the background sprites, use `SKAction` instead since you have more control over timing. The motion within `update` won't be consistant because, unless you have an algorithm to control exactly when `update:` is called, you will see that the movement speeds up or slows down. To move the background, use code that looks something like this after your `didMoveToView` method:

```
var backgroundMovement = SKAction.moveByX(background.size.x, y: 0, duration: someDuration)
background.runAction(background, completion: {() -> Void in
    //place background image at start again
    background.position = ...
})
```

Loop this code if you want the background to move continuously and edit it in any way you'd like to make it look better (like having both backgrounds move with SKAction). Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks :) 1 question. With the code i am using, how can i make it like it spawn more then 1 image? So its loops a roll with 2-3 images?

Comment: well, you currently have a loop thats using two images at once, but its not necessarily looping the right way. I think you'd need to modify the code you are using now quite a bit

Comment: you need to have the nodes be interconnected. Once one background comes off the screen, you spawn it after the next and keep the cycle going. I'm really trying to help you here but I can't just write all of the code...